# The value in TextInput is not getting changed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am a newcomer to react native and struggling with the following issue. I am doing an update function, once a user is selected then this user's data is populated into their dedicated fields `TextInput` like `given_name`, `family_name` and so on. The problem is when I try to modify the populated data from any `TextInput` it won't allow me as the text will not change at all and remain fixed as what it is no matter what. I am aware this is happening because the `value` of my fields are assigned to the incoming data that I want to update but how do I fix that and be able to modify this value ?

I would appreciate if you can help.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    given_name: '',
    family_name: '',
    email: '',
    password: '',
    UserInfo: '',
  };
}

handleGivenName = (text) => {
  this.setState({
    given_name: text
  })
}
handleLastName = (text) => {
  this.setState({
    family_name: text
  })
}
handleEmail = (text) => {
  this.setState({
    email: text
  })
}
handlePass = (text) => {
  this.setState({
    password: text
  })
}

<TextInput placeholder="Last Name"
           onChangeText={ this.handleLastName }
           value={ this.state.UserInfo.family_name } />
```

Comment: What does your `<TextInput />` component code looks like?

Comment: `<TextInput  placeholder="Last Name" onChangeText={this.handleLastName} value = {this.state.UserInfo.family_name} />`

Comment: @Khaled I think palaѕн wanted to know what the component definition of `TextInput` looks like?

Comment: component definition ! sorry what is that ?

Comment: @Khaled It's where the `TextInput` component is defined. Not your custom instance. See: [`TextInput.js`](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Components/TextInput/TextInput.js)

Comment: Is it where I import it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use an arrow-function in `onChangeText`:

```
handleLastName(text) {
  this.setState({
    family_name: text,
    userInfo: { ...this.state.userInfo, family_name: text}
  })
}
```

**render():**

```
<TextInput   
placeholder="Last Name" 
onChangeText={(text) => this.handleLastName(text)} 
value={this.state.family_name} // remove UserInfo
/>
```

Comment: The populated data is stored in UserInfo, if I removed it the textinput would be empty @Tim

Answer (score 0):

you are reading value from a property `this.state.UserInfo.family_name` and update another one in change handler `this.setState({ family_name: text })` that makes your value read-only; either update change handler or the value you are passing to the `TextInput`;
your code is similar to this :

```
state = {
 a: 1,
 b: 2
}

changeHandler(e){
setState( { b: e.value } )

render(){
 <TextInput value={b} />
   ....
```